# How can "als" be appended with a genitive case?

Tags: genitive, conjunction

In *Sein und Zeit*, there is such a sentence:

> Die Interpretation der Zeit als des möglichen Horizontes eines jeden Seinsverständnisses überhaupt ist ihr vorläufiges Ziel.
> ("ihr" refers to Sein und Zeit)

The *des möglichen Horizontes* in this sentence seems to be in genitive case.  But *als* will not be used with a
genitive case seemingly.

I tried to understand the sentence regardless of the problem of case. In this way, the sentence seems to mean something like: *The interpretation of time as the possible horizon of an understanding of being is its goal*

But when I compare my understanding with the translation into my native language. I found that I was wrong. Moreover, I don't know how to interpret the *überhaupt* and *jeden* in the sentence.

The *jeden* seems to be not in genitive case, so how can it be used with *Seinsverständnisses*, a noun seems to be in genitive case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Als* is not a preposition -- it is a conjunction. As such, it does not "take a case".  The case of the dominated phrase is determined by the syntactic environment.

In your example, *als* is used in an apposition-like fashion, to add further information to an NP.  And so the case inside the *als*-phrase needs to be the same as in the reference phrase.  All of these are possible:

- Nominative: ***Die Zeit als der mögliche Horizont** ist Seinsverständnis.*
- Genitive: *Die Interpretation **der Zeit als des möglichen Horizontes** ist das Ziel.*
- Dative: ***Der Zeit als dem möglichen Horizont** können wir das Ziel zuschreiben.*
- Accusative: *Wir sehen **die Zeit als den möglichen Horizont** eines jeden Seinsverständnisses.*

(I am just reusing your vocabulary -- no preservation of meaning is intended.)

---

*Jeden* is just an adjective modifying *Seinsverständnisses*, and indeed the correctly inflected weak neutrum genitive.

*Überhaupt* is perhaps difficult to translate. In a philosophical context like yours, it used to mark something as "fundamental", or ["concerning the core concept underlying a notion"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamentalontologie).  It behaves mostly like an adverb, but you can also postfix it it a noun phrase.  Using it makes you sound more Heideggerian:

> Dies geschah und
> geschieht so wesentlich, daß die Dinge nicht nur nicht mehr als Dinge zugelassen sind,
> sondern daß die Dinge überhaupt noch nie zu erscheinen vermochten.

> Warum ist überhaupt Seiendes und nicht vielmehr Nichts?

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, in this way, the noun-phrase between "als" and "überhaupt" is in genitive case only because "der Zeit" before it is in genitive case.

Comment: Still one more question: Can I interpret the "überhaupt" as an adverb decorating the "als"?  So the phrase would be understood as "The interpretation of time fundamentally as ...".  It seems to quite make sense.

Comment: By the way, there seem to be a little mistake in your answer. The word in the sentence is "Seinsverständnisses" instead of "Selbstverständnisses".

Comment: _Überhaupt_ modifies _des möglichen Horizontes eines jeden Seinsverständnisses_.

Answer (score -2):

This sentence is hardly making any sense in modern German. If the text is old *) chances are it was not originally capitalized and only later edited, perhaps introducing a mistake when this question was written.

> als des möglichen Horizontes

is ungrammatical (to me). It's either *als Horizont* or *als Horizont des Möglichen / des Möglichen Horizont* (disagreeing with @Phibsgabler), unless the Genitive is commanded by something other than *des*. However, in older speech, it's possible that things were different, but Grimm (DWB) doesn't mention *genitiv* nor *als des* in the respective entry. Also, I cannot find *des möglichen* as an adverbial phrase (as if *of course, per chance*).

Under these conditions, I find it diffuclt to judge how it should be read correctly. I have to admit for the sake of agreement, it is tempting to append one *-s* to many.

*) I have to guess since you have not given a proper reference of authorship

DWB: Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm. Lfg. 2 (1852), Bd. I (1854): https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/als

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sein_und_Zeit

Comment: To be frank, I have a feeling rather similar to yours, because in my grammar book I cannot find any grammar rule that can be used to parse this sentence. So I have to assume that this sentence is constructed in a way which is uncommon but understandable to native speakers. Moreover, sadly, I copied the sentence from a printed book whose ISBN is 3484701226, and double checked the sentence.